# selecting queries only 3 queries that starts with an alphabet "i" in sqlite3

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table with two attribute word and frequency. Now,I want to select those word which starts with "i" but only 3 of them

for example :

I have 180 words starting with an i

`I
Is
It
.
.
.`

now i want to select 1st three words that starts with 'i'

Thankyou

Comment: Hint:  `LIMIT`, `LIKE`.

Comment: Search for "sqlite select top records" or a similar search. (Since sqlite uses SQL, searching for "SQL select top records" or similar may also work.)

Comment: The records in a sqlite table might not be in the order you would expect. So you should ORDER BY so that the TOP or LIMIT records you take are the ones you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `LIKE`, `LIMIT` and optionally `ORDER BY` (if you need to retrieve top values from a ordered list otherwise comment it) as below.

```
select words 
from table1
where words like 'i%'
order by words asc
limit 3;
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/RXBWU21444)**